# How to define a Rcpp package based on several different cpp files?

Tags: r, rcpp

I have define several .cpp files.
One of them needs the package RcppArmadillo;
The others need the package Rcpp.

After my Rcpp package is generated and when i install it, I compile several errors as follows:

```
RcppExports.cpp:49: error: ‘arma’ has not been declared
RcppExports.cpp:49: error: ‘arma’ has not been declared
RcppExports.cpp:49: error: expected `;' before ‘__result’
RcppExports.cpp:50: error: ‘__result’ was not declared in this scope
make: *** [RcppExports.o] Error 1
```

When I check RcppExports.cpp file in src, the include head is like this:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
```

What should I do? How to handle this problem? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is extensively documented, and there are thirty CRAN packages using RcppArmadillo you could look at for working examples and guidance.

Start with

```
RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton()
```

to create an (almost empty) working package for RcppArmadillo, then drop your files in the `src/` directory of that package.

The `RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton()` has options, so consider reading its help page. The `Rcpp` package has a lot of documentation you may want to look at too, including *one entire vignette* about package building.